# Get number of likes and comments of a site page and display it in fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages

Is there a way I can get the total number of likes and comments in the site page and display it in fields (metadata).

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of likes and comments, we can use powershell:

```
#Connect to SPO site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<TENANT-NAME>.sharepoint.com/sites/<YOUR-SITE>

#Store pages into a variable
$sitePagesGallery = Get-PnPList -Identity "Site Pages"

#Get the pages details 
$logFile = "C:\users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\LikesAndComments.csv"
$results = @()

foreach ($item in $sitePagesGallery) {
$allPages = Get-PnPListItem -List $sitePagesGallery -Fields "FileLeafRef", "Title", "ID", "FileRef", "_CommentCount", "_LikeCount"

#Choose the properties to export
foreach ($page in $allPages) {
    $results += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Title         = $page["Title"]
        ID            = $page.ID
        FullPath      = $page["FileRef"]
        NumOfComments = $page["_CommentCount"]
        NumOfLikes    = $page["_LikeCount"]        
    }
}
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path $logFile -NoTypeInformation
```

To display it in fields, I'm afraid there is no OOTB way. You may need to use custom codes and integrate with Power Automate.